# CSOM Property for Access Request Group

Tags: powershell, csom

Our tenant received a new feature which allows for access requests to be directed to the `$Context.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup` property. This is a nice feature because you can now have it automatically notify the owners instead of a distribution list or comma separated list of email addresses. Below is a screenshot from [Microsoft's page on the feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3).

[image: Access Request Settings]

Previously to return the list of emails/individual for receiving the emails you could run this sequence to retrieve the property.

```
$Context.Web.Retrieve('RequestAccessEmail')
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Context.Web.RequestAccessEmail
useremail@contoso.com
```

I have found that you can see the `accessrequestsitedescription` property by pulling all properties for the site.

```
$Context.Load($Context.Web.AllProperties)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Context.Web.AllProperties.FieldValues.accessrequestsitedescription
Test Message
```

What I am trying to determine is how to identify if the Access Request configuration is pointing to the `$Context.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup`, or just not configured at all. I have also confirmed that `Get-PnPRequestAccessEmails` does not return this information as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround until an interface is published or the CSOM is updated. All it needs is an authenticated CSOM Context object or an authenticated `WebRequestSession` against the tenant.

I am using this to make sure someone is going to receive access requests if they are enabled, and that the employee is still with the organization through other checks with our Active Directory.

```
# Build an SPOSession using the $Context object to pull an authentication cookie for that user.
$SPOSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$SPOSession.Cookies.SetCookies($Context.Url, $Context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($Context.Url, $true))
$SPOSession.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")

# Pull the data down using the SPOSession cookie
$URL = $Context.Url + '/_layouts/15/setrqacc.aspx?type=web'
$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $SPOSession -Method GET -Uri $URL

# Parse the HTML for member sharing settings.
$MembersCanShare = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_chkMembersCanShare')).getAttribute('checked')
$MembersCanInvite = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_chkMembersCanAddToGroup')).getAttribute('checked') 

# Parse the HTML for Access Requests
$AccessRequestsAllowed = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_chkRequestAccess')).getAttribute('checked') 
$AccessRecipientGroup = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl04_defaultValue')).getAttribute('checked') 
$AccessRecipientUsers = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl04_otherValue')).getAttribute('checked') 
$RequestMessage = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl04_txtAccreqCustomMsg')).InnerText
If($AccessRequestsAllowed -AND $AccessRecipientGroup)
{
    $AccessRecipientType = 'Group'
    $AccessRecipientName = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl04_labelDefaultSection')).InnerText
}
ElseIf($AccessRequestsAllowed -AND $AccessRecipientUsers)
{
    $AccessRecipientType = 'Email'
    $AccessRecipientName = ($Data.ParsedHtml.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl04_txtEmail1')).Value
}
Else
{
    $AccessRecipientType = 'Disabled'
    $AccessRecipientName = 'None'
}
# Build a PSObject to pass
$AccessRequestObj = New-Object PSObject -Property `
    @{ 'MembersCanShare'         = $MembersCanShare;
       'MembersCanInvite'        = $MembersCanInvite;
       'AccessRequests'          = $AccessRequestsAllowed;
       'AccessRecipientType'     = $AccessRecipientType;
       'AccessRecipient'         = $AccessRecipientName;
       'AccessDeniedMessage'     = $RequestMessage;
     }
# Return or manipulate further
```

Sample output:

```
$AccessRequestObj | Format-List
AccessDeniedMessage : This is a sample custom message to users who receive access denied.
MembersCanShare     : True
AccessRecipient     : AccessRecipient@contoso.com
AccessRequests      : True
AccessRecipientType : Email
MembersCanInvite    : False
```

Comment: Hello i tried this script but its not working for me. the GetElementbyID is always null and GetAttribute cause an error. Can you check if its working for you? Or something what i need to do?

Comment: I found that if you have the default members group removed it will error out due to a null entry, specifically when it creates the `$MembersCanInvite` variable. Do you have a default members group? See the screenshot here that I tested it on to see that error. https://i.imgur.com/23su5YJ.png